# Mounting OS specific volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to setup a filebeat docker container which needs access to the produced docker logs from all the other running containers. For this purpose I mount a volume like this:

```
  filebeat:
    build: filebeat
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/containers:/var/lib/docker/containers:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - elk
```

**My problem:**

The path to the docker logs is dependent on the machine docker-compose is running. The above works for Linux, but it doesn't work on my windows machine. When I run the above I get the following error:

> ERROR: for filebeat  Cannot create container for service filebeat:
>   b'Mount denied:\nThe source path
>   "\\var\\lib\\docker\\containers:/var/lib/docker/containers"\nis
>   not a valid Windows path'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS` env variable to 1. Using the Windows Powershell just run these commands:

```
$Env:COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS = "1"
```

To check if it's actually set run: `$Env:COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS`

Then just restart docker-compose:

```
docker-compose stop
docker-compose up
```